# Multisite SVN repository replication - Based on time

Tags: svn, replication, visualsvn-server

I am working on multisite repository replication using VisualSVN Server. The replication between master and slave is working fine. My requirement is based on the **scheduling time** the synchronization should happen between master to slave and vice versa.

Here is an example: master repository is in India and slave repository is in the USA. Based on the time for e.g. 7:00 PM IST the sync should start from **master to slave** and 6:00 AM IST the sync should happen from **slave to master**.

Updating the question based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603262/multisite-svn-repository-replication-based-on-time/43656319?noredirect=1#comment74549108_43656319):

I am looking for scheduled replication for the following scenario. Let us assume that master SVN repository is in India and slave SVN repository is in US.

Both master and slave are modifying on the same file, same line with different content. Assume that both have the same HEAD revision(100). Now slave commit first (101 revision), and next second there was network issues. Meanwhile master SVN repo also committing (101 revision). Now let's assume that the network issue is solved. Now at the time of sync, how this conflict scenario can be handled?

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Can anyone please help on this!

Comment: Why do you look for scheduled replication? What's the case?

Answer (score 0):

> Both master and slave are modifying on the same file, same line with
>   different content. Assume that both have the same HEAD revision(100).
>   Now slave commit first (101 revision), and next second there was
>   network issues. Meanwhile master SVN repo also committing (101
>   revision). Now let's assume that the network issue is solved. Now at
>   the time of sync, how this conflict scenario can be handled?

There should be no conflicts by design. VDFS follows master-slave replication architecture and master VDFS service ensures that the transactions are committed in proper sequence and do not conflict.

You might want to read the article [KB84: Comparing VDFS with master-master replication solutions](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00084/).

---

VDFS replication is performed instantly and automatically and does not have any special replication scheduling now. VDFS slave repositories require access to the master repository in order to be writable. If the slave is unable to access its master, this VDFS slave is working in Read Only mode.

In case keeping Read Only slaves and enabling the replication on schedule is what you look for, you could use Windows Task Manager to Start and Stop VDFS service at required time or run the PowerShell cmdlets [`Suspend-SvnRepository`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Suspend-SvnRepository) and [`Resume-SvnRepository`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Resume-SvnRepository).

Comment: Thanks Bahrep, I'm looking for Scheduling replication for the following scenario. 

Let us assume that Master is in India and Slave is in US. Both Master and slave are modifying on the **same file , same line with different content**. Assume that both have the same head revision(100). Now Slave commit first (101 revision), and next second there was network issues. Meanwhile Master also committing (101 revision). Now let's assume that network issue is solved. Now at the time of sync, how this conflict scenario can be handled ? Can you please help me.

Comment: can any one please help on this!

Comment: @sangeethakannan I've updated the answer. VDFS guarantees that the situation that you describe does never happen, therefore I'm not sure what kind of help you look for.